# OpenLayers Google Satellite plugin datum error

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I import NAD83 latitude/longitude data (EPSG 4269), and the coordinate values displayed are correct. I enable on-the-fly (OTF), then import Google Satellite data, which is automatically WGS84 Pseudo Mercator (EPSG 3857). The coordinate values are corrupted, but the vector overlay looks spatially correct on the Google map.

If I now assign the coordinate system back to NAD83 EPSG 4269, the coordinates for the vector layer are correct, but the Google layer has shifted and will not zoom correctly. I've tried all combinations of loading and assigning datums and all fail. It appears the problem is the Google Pseudo Mercator datum; I tried transforming the vector layer into WGS72 and NAD83 UTM Zone 11 and all was fine. It appears that once a Google layer is imported you are stuck with bad coordinates.

Note I have tried this on QGIS v1.8.0 and 2.14.0 and different operating systems.

Comment: Not a QGIS user so asking others--is there an odd proj.4 definition of EPSG:3857 in QGIS? I am wondering if you're somehow ending up with the equivalent of EPSG:3395 (World Mercator) rather than true Pseudo Mercator.

Comment: The Google layer is loaded and identified as EPSG:3857 Pseido/Mercator. The vector layer is NAD 83 degrees EPSG:4265

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super sure what the question you're asking is, but I might suggest using the QuickMapServices plugin and see if you have the same issues.  In my experiences QMS works much better than the OpenLayers plugin

Comment: I looked at the QMS sources and they wre no better. The area is quite remote and not covered well by all sources.

Comment: QMS also has the same Google services as the Openlayers plugin. You have to enable them in the plugin settings with `Get Contributed Pack`. For licensing issues they are not included by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a shift of about 20km northwards, it is a Pseudo Mercator issue.

Openlayers requires EPSG:3857 as layer **and** project CRS. The vector layer can have another CRS, like NAD83 degrees. Check `Set Layer CRS` to see if it is correct, don't use `Save As ...` in this step.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are implying a particular sequence for loading layers and setting CRS. The NAD 83 EPSG 4265 layer is loaded first, and OTF set. When the google layer is added the datum is automatically set as combined EPSG 3857, but the coordinates are drastically wrong, however the vector layer looks good - meaning they are pipelines and you can see them correctly overlayed on the image. If I Set Layer CRS to NAD 83 the coordinates are correct on the vector layer, but the Google layer is shifted about 90 m west.

Comment: Apart from using QMS, you should start with the project CRS of EPSG:3857. Then load Google imagery, then the vector data. Set the layer CRS so they align. In the Project properties, general tab, you can change the display units between meters and degrees. Remember that EPSG:3857 does not use real meters, they are stretched towards the poles.

Comment: Yes I tried that - set OTF and then EPSG:3857 for Google imagery. I loaded Google (no display since it is effectively global coverage at this point) then loaded the vector NAD83 degrees layer. The area of coverage was correct but coordinates are wrong. With OTF it should transform between either datum. I tried QMS but did not find any decent satellite coverage. BTW - Bing aerial has the same issue as Google.

Comment: Just a follow up - when I load the shapefiles into Google Earth Pro they are correct in every sense; location,scale, and coordinate values. I have tried all combinations I can think of for entering the data in QGIS and the coordinates are always corrupted.

Comment: Can you give an example pair of lon/lat coordinates, and what values QGIS displays? Did you enable the `Contributed Pack` in QMS, which provides Google Satellite imagery as well?

Comment: A simple polygon in WGS84 lat/long has the NW corner of -116.8038, 56.3636 I then load Google Satellite from the OpenLayers plugin, and the NW corner is-13002519, 7631562. The datum is EPSG3857 with OTF. If I check the CRS of the vector layer it is EPSG3857, presumably transformed to the Google layer CRS. If I right click the vector layer, and set the CRS to it's native WGS84, the coordinates are correct but the Google image has shifted. I did not find the Contributed Pack or a simple way to enable it. There are 7 layers under QMS (Landsat, MapQuest etc.)

Comment: Note that the coordinates in the bottom line are **project** CRS, while the polygon layer can have a different CRS. You can change the coordinates display to degree with `Project -> Project Properties`, `General` tab, `Coordinate Display` section (only in the latest QGIS version). To get full QMS, go to `Web -> QuickMap Services -> Settings`, `More services` tab, `Get contributed pack`.

Comment: Yes, when I import the polygon in degrees and coordiante display is correct, then import Google satellite, the coordinate display is incorrect. Under Project Properties  I can switchback to degrees and the coordinate display is correct, but I cannot get a correct coordinate display in metres (Pseudo Mercator).  Maybe something more fundamental is wrong. I'll outline that in a new post.Thanks for the QMS info.

Comment: When I import the polygon, the Layer panel is grayed out, I cannot get info on any layers. I have to check the Control rendering order to get access to the layers. This is not like older versions. Also, I don't get info on the layer with a right click, I have to go to the Layer drop down. The CRS is correct for the polygon and OTF is enabled. When I import Google, I can query the polygon CRS under layer /properties and it is correct, but the Google layer returns the same CRS as the polygon, not Pseudo Mercator.